# Deactivate input in react with a button click

Tags: button, input, reactjs, onclick, components

I have this basic component and I want the textfield to be deactivated or activated whenever I click on a button. How can I achieve this?

This is my sample code:

```
import React from "react";
import Button from 'react-button'

const Typing = (props) => {
    var disabled = "disabled";
    var enabled = !disabled;

  const handleUserInput = (event) => props.onUserInput(event.target.value);
  const handleGameClik = (props) => {

      disabled = enabled;
  }
  return(
      <div>

          <input
              className = "typing-container"
              value = {props.currentInput}
              onChange = {handleUserInput}
              placeholder=" ^__^ "
              disabled = {disabled}/>
          <Button  onClick = {handleGameClik}> Start Game  </Button>
          <Button> Fetch Data </Button>

          </div>
          );
};
```

Comment: You need to store `disable` variable in component `state` and change it there. When you change the state of the component, the `render` method will invoke and refresh the component.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

A simplified solution using state could look like this:

```
class Typing extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { disabled: false }
  }
  handleGameClik() {
    this.setState( {disabled: !this.state.disabled} )
  } 
  render() {
    return(
        <div>
          <input
                className = "typing-container"
                placeholder= " type here "
                disabled = {(this.state.disabled)? "disabled" : ""}/>
          <button  onClick = {this.handleGameClik.bind(this)}> Start Game  </button>
          <button> Fetch Data </button>
        </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Working [Codepen here](http://codepen.io/wintvelt/pen/ZWjQXR?editors=0010).

Comment: You do not need to do `{(this.state.disabled)? "disabled" : ""}` when a prop is false || null it is automatically ommited. `disabled={this.state.disabled}` is enough.

Comment: Besides, both `disabled="disabled"` and `disabled=""` mean the input is disabled in HTML. Boolean attributes are false when the attribute is removed, not set to an empty string. In fact, this answer should definitely be edited to remove that incorrect code.

Comment: @Domino I agree that my code could be a bit cleaner/ nicer, but it is not incorrect. you can see in the working codepen that the example code just works, so “disabled” and “” do not mean the same thing in react/jsx. Today, I would probably use hooks and something like `<input disabled={this.state.disabled}`.

Comment: Ah, I see. React doesn't actually call `element.setAttribute("disabled", "")` but probably translates that into `element.disabled = ""` and the empty string is false. That sure is a quirk to keep in mind.

Answer (score 33):

## ** 2019 **

Another option is to use, react-hooks' hook `useState`.

Edit: In a functional component

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

function Typing(props) {
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);

  function handleGameClick() {
    setDisabled(!disabled);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        className='typing-container'
        placeholder=' type here '
        disabled={disabled}
      />
      <button type='submit' onClick={handleGameClick}> Start Game </button>
      <button> Fetch Data </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Or, if your `disabled` state depends on some other prop or state item, use [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo).

Comment: react-hooks' hook -> functional component

Comment: This is a better solution

Answer (score 12):

This might confuse you, but the guys at React.js actually rebuild every form component and made them look almost exactly like the native HTML component. There are some differences however.

In HTML you should disable an input field like this:

```
<input disabled="disabled" />
```

But in React.js you'll have to use:

```
<input disabled={true} />
```

The accepted example works because anything not `0` is considered `true`. Therefor `"disabled"` is also interpreted as `true`.

Answer (score -2):

```
const [disabled , setDisabled] = useState(true) 
if(condition){ 
 setDisabled(false)
}else{ 
 setDisabled(true) 
} 
return
<TextField placeholder="Name" disabled={ disabled} />
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.